# Unity Video Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, video

I am failing at playing a simple video under unity free 2017.1.0f3 personal

I am working on a game and I'd like to play an introduction video at the start of the app. Then move onto the login screen whenever the player clicks it.

I have created a video player object, dragged and dropped the video clip (mp4) into the video clip field of the object.

I then attached the object to the camera. In the script attached to the camera I created a public VideoPlayer that I have populated with the video player object.

I then execute :

```
void Awake ()
{
VideoPlayer.Play();
}
```

But nothing happens.

Perhaps it should be executed within a separate thread (coroutine)? I tried but did not work either.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Provided you filled the right settings, if it still doesn't play but you get no error, no freeze, no nothing.

Trying restarting Unity.

(I struggled for 45 min trying to figure out why my video wouldn't play anymore until I restarted Unity and it magically reworked)

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the Video can be played back by unity?

put a quad in front of your camera, put a videocomponent on there, check Loop and playonAwake, hit Play and see if it works.

```
GameObjectWithPlayerComponentAttatched.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Play();
```

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign the RenderTexture?

What I do is create a RenderTexture, then assign it to the videoplayer, then add a Raw Image and then give it the RenderTexture in the Texture field.

You should uncheck play onAwake if you want to play it at a certain point, instead of videoplayer.Play, use videoPlayer.
Prepare and prepareCompleted Play the video. 
Like this:

```
private void Start()
{
    videoPlayer.prepareCompleted += VideoPlayer_prepareCompleted;
    videoPlayer.Prepare();
}

private void VideoPlayer_prepareCompleted(VideoPlayer source)
{
    videoPlayer.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Video Player has three modes: Render Texture -- and then you need to select a RenderTexture to render to, Material Override -- and then it needs a mesh to write to its material, and Camera -- then you need to assign a camera and select to render to the near or far plane.

To have the camera feature work automatically, you need to instantiate the VideoPlayer script on the camera object itself.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps to play a video using unity's VideoPlayer component:

1. Create a **plane**, under 3d Objects.
2. Add a **VideoPlayer** component to that plane.
3. Set **render mode** as **Material Override**.
4. Drag the **mesh renderer** component of the plane to the videoplayer's **renderer** field.
5. Select a video clip to play and enable **play on awake**.
6. Press play in the editor window.

[image]